# Find/replace text string containing the character '*' with cscope

Tags: regex, string, cscope

The cscope program allows finding/replacing text in a full C code distributed in many files, and navigating easily through the source code. Does anyone know how to search-and-replace patterns that contain the character '*' with cscope?

Whenever I look for a string containing '*' I always get the error message "Could not find the text string: *ptr" (here I looked for '*ptr' which does exists in the code).

According to the source code of cscope (I am using version 15.7a), "findstring" will just escape the characters '. * [ \ ^ $ + ? | ( ) ' with '\' and then search for an egrep pattern ('find.c' @ line 474).

Using directly egrep on a given file and escaping '*' with '\' works. Using cscope to find an egrep pattern instead of a string does not work either.

Comment: Try using `[*]` or replacing the literal asterisk with \x2A or \u002A.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I completely misunderstood the point of your comment at first. Using "Find this egrep pattern" and *not* "Find this text string", and then using `[*]`, works. You may want to post that as an answer. `\x` or `\u` doesn't work.

Comment: @hvd Thank you for sharing. I suggested most common workarounds for sprcial character literal matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You happened to have picked a buggy version of cscope. It was reported as not working in version 15.8a but working in 15.5, so broke somewhere in between. It was fixed again and works as expected in 15.8b.

More details at [#87 special char escaping broken in 15.8 in egrep](http://sourceforge.net/p/cscope/patches/87/)

You're testing by using the `egrep` command-line utility, but that isn't what's used by cscope. cscope is using a custom regex implementation, see `src/egrep.y`. The bug was in there.

Comment: Thank you very much, this fixed the problem. Note however that the latest release announced in the official cscope page is 15.8a (release 15.8b is however available following the link in SourceForge, and seems to be stable).

Answer (score 1):

You can always use an old trick to place "magic characters" into a character class (`[...]`) to match them as literal characters.

Use `[*]` to find a literal asterisk symbol.